# How to upload file using Java Google Drive API

Tags: java, google-drive-api

I would like to upload a file using Google Drive API. I have looked at [Google Drive API for Java](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/quickstart/java) and [Google Drive API Javadoc](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/drive/v3/java/latest/), but I don't see anything.

Comment: I think [this](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/manage-uploads) is what you're looking for?

Comment: @Polyov that is not using Java API

Comment: If you scroll down to [here](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/manage-uploads#importing_to_google_docs_types_wzxhzdk8wzxhzdk9) you'll see that they have examples for multiple languages, including Java. The first part just deals with the technical aspects of the REST api.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [upload file into google drive using java api](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16235399/upload-file-into-google-drive-using-java-api)

Comment: Have you resolved this?

Answer (score 4):

The [Uploading Files](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/manage-uploads) in Drive API that @Polyov gave you contains a Java code snippet:

```
File fileMetadata = new File();
fileMetadata.setName("My Report");
fileMetadata.setMimeType("application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet");

java.io.File filePath = new java.io.File("files/report.csv");
FileContent mediaContent = new FileContent("text/csv", filePath);
File file = driveService.files().create(fileMetadata, mediaContent)
.setFields("id")
.execute();
System.out.println("File ID: " + file.getId());
```

Whichever language you use, the concepts remain the same like there will always be the 3 types of uploading, namely: simple upload, multipart and resumable.

There's a [Java Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/quickstart/java) to get you started.

If you're looking for more code samples check this [github repo](https://github.com/google/google-api-java-client-samples/blob/master/drive-cmdline-sample/src/main/java/com/google/api/services/samples/drive/cmdline/DriveSample.java) for your reference.

Comment: I don't think this is multipath upload.